# how can I avoid tqdm to jump a line every interation in 2 progress bars

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

What can I do to avoid tqdm, jumps a lane every iteration??

```
import time

from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

pbar1=tqdm_notebook(total=10000)
for i in range(10):
    pbar2=tqdm_notebook(total=1000,leave=False)
    for j in range(1000):
        time.sleep(0.001)
        pbar1.update(1)
        pbar2.update(1)
    pbar2.close()
```

[starting the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20zmK.jpg)

[few iterations later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ce5I.jpg)

notice i need to do like this , this is just a test I am trying to use tqdm iterating files, so i can not call the func inside the loop.

Any HInt???

Thanks!